# How do I save an integer once in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults

Im making a game and when the user collects an orb I want it to save in an lael but only once. I got it to save the integer in a label but need help with not letting the the orb be saved more than once. Here is the code Im using:

```
if firstBody.categoryBitMask == HeroCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == OrbCategory {

        //saves orbs

        UserDefaults().set(UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "saveOrbs")+1, forKey:"saveOrbs")
        UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "saveOrbs").description

        orbLabel.text = UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "saveOrbs").description


}
```

Comment: I don't have the answer for you - unless you meant how do I set a flag to only save something once (which means you've really done some poor design) - but I think you are really asking something your question title doesn't say. Please - be more specific! If you are using bit masks, include some more code. If you are using UserDefaults, include that in the title if appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using UserDefaults for this? It seems that a normal variable would be enough. In that case, you can use an optional variable, making the check even easier.

Comment: Basically what I want is if the user already collected the orb than not to add +1 to the label. I used UserDefaults so I can save the integer to the label.

Comment: @coding22 you should use `UserDefaults` when you wish to keep a value in the internal storage of the phone, so that the value is persistent even if you close and reopen the app. From what I understand, you don't need to use `UserDefaults`, but a simple boolean flag that holds whether the orb is collected or not. Or more simply, you can use an optional integer (`Int?`) and check whether its value is nil or not each time the user tries to pick up the orb.

Comment: I also want to save the orb to a label. I got that to work already just need help with not letting the orb be counted as an integer more than once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try checking the key before setting it like

```
if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "haveSavedOrb")  == nil {
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "haveSavedOrb")
UserDefaults.standard.set(orbs + 1, forKey: "saveOrbs")
}
```

Comment: Im not at home so I cannot check if the method names are exactly right but this should give you an idea, your question wasn't specific so sorry if this wasn't what you were looking for.

Comment: I didnt downvote you btw.  I only need it to add +1 to the label when the user collects the orb the first time and after that it shouldnt add +1 to the label.

Comment: So you want the label to be set to 1 when the user gets an orb?

Comment: Do you need to use UserDefaults?

Comment: Yeah I already got that to work but when the user gets the orb again I dont want it to add another +1 to the label. Yes I need user defaults to save the label.

Comment: Is there a way to add a flag instead of using nil because I have other levels with orbs that I would like to add to the label?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133850/discussion-between-coding22-and-timmy).

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3:

To set the value `100` for the key `MyInt`

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(100, forKey: "MyInt")
```

And later to retrieve the value for `MyInt`.

```
let myInt = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "MyInt")
```